# Where is root directory - Parrot Linux

Tags: directory, parrotsec

Need some assistance as I'm trying to learn how to do some simple scripting.

I run command line as `sudo`.

I then run the

```
mkdir bin
```

Afterwards, I create a test file using `vim newtestfile.sh`

I'm trying to figure out where it's located. It says the location is at `/root/bin`.

From what I understood it's my home directory...? Can someone direct to the path?

Comment: Is the question "what's the path to `/root/bin`?"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind all. I found it and there was actually a folder called `root` inside the file systems folder.

Reason I was confused because I thought `root` meant something else.

Comment: `root` is the *home* directory of the user **root**. As you are using  *sudo* for the mkdir command then it is located in root's home.